# Using struct, functions and pointers, I am trying to convert the follwoing C++ code to C, but its not working

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I am trying to convert this C++ code to C. The C++ class needs to be converted to struct.

Also, we need to use pointers.

Following is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
class rectangle {
private:
    double width,height;
public:
    rectangle(double w, double h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    double get_area() {
        return width * height;
    }
    bool compare(rectangle* rf) {
        return (this->get_area() > rf->get_area());
    }
};
int main() {
    rectangle* r1=new rectangle(1.5,2.6);
    rectangle* r2=new rectangle(2.5,1.6);
    bool ans=r1->compare(r2);
    printf("%s\n", ans?"true":"false");
    return 0;
}
```

My code in C does not raise any errors but does not print anything. Here is my code. Cannot seem to find the issue. Can you please help out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Rectangle
{
    double width;
    double height;
    
    void (*new_rectangle)(double, double);
    double (*get_area)();
    bool (*compare)(struct Rectangle*);
    
};

void new_rectangle(struct Rectangle* self, double w, double h) 
{
    self->width = w;
    self->height = h;
}

double get_area(struct Rectangle* self)
{
    return self->width*self->height;
}   

bool compare(struct Rectangle* this, struct Rectangle* other) {
    return (this->get_area() > other->get_area());
}


int main()
{   
    struct Rectangle* r1;
    new_rectangle(r1, 1.5, 2.6);
    struct Rectangle* r2;
    new_rectangle(r2, 2.5, 1.6);
    bool ans = r1->compare(r2);
    printf("%s\n", ans?"true":"false");
    
    // printf("%c", );
//  bool ans=r1->compare(r2);
//  printer(r1)
//  printf("%s\n", ans?"true":"false");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No errors? Then turn up the warning level: `*r1 `and `*r2` have no memory allocation.

Comment: You never create any instances of `Rectangle`. All the pointers are left uninitialized.

Comment: You can't replace non-static member functions with function pointers like this. Just use free functions in C. You cannot translate from one programming language to another line-by-line. You need to think about the behavior in the original language and then write a program in the target language with the expected behavior.

Comment: And even after you do allocate memory for `*r1, *r2`, you also have to initialize their function pointer members.  `struct Rectangle` has a member called `compare`, and you have a function called `compare`, but they have nothing to do with each other; the former doesn't somehow get automatically initialized to point to the latter.  You would have to do it yourself in a constructor-like function.

Comment: Normally the only reason to actually use a function pointer member in the struct is if different instances of `struct Rectangle` should use pointers to different functions, i.e. polymorphism, like C++'s `virtual` functions.   Your pointers are the analogue of the virtual method table. But your functions are in effect not `virtual`, so here there is no point except to waste memory.

Comment: Anony1234321, With `struct Rectangle* r1;  new_rectangle(r1, 1.5, 2.6);`, code passes an uninitialized pointer to `new_rectangle()`.  Passing garbage with end badly.  Why pass an uninitialized value?

Comment: Another important C vs C++ difference: a function taking no arguments mustn't be declared like `int main() { ... }`, but like `int main(void) { ... }`.  This issue arises in particular with `double (*get_area)();`.  The empty parentheses don't mean "no arguments", they mean "unspecified arguments".  As it stands you could call `r1->get_area(1,2,3,4,5);` and the compiler would not warn you in any way.  So you would want `double (*get_area)(void);`.

Comment: Why make `r1` and `r2` structures instead of pointers as they are in c++?

Answer (score 3):

Your C code is not setting up the function pointers in the `struct`, and is not using pointers correctly in `main()`.

Try this instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Rectangle
{
    double width;
    double height;
    
    double (*get_area)(struct Rectangle*);
    bool (*compare)(struct Rectangle*);
};

double get_area(struct Rectangle* this)
{
    return this->width * this->height;
}   

bool compare(struct Rectangle* this, struct Rectangle* other) {
    return this->get_area(this) > other->get_area(other);
}

void new_rectangle(struct Rectangle* this, double w, double h) 
{
    this->width = w;
    this->height = h;
    this->get_area = &get_area;
    this->compare = &compare;
}

int main()
{   
    struct Rectangle r1;
    new_rectangle(&r1, 1.5, 2.6);
    struct Rectangle r2;
    new_rectangle(&r2, 2.5, 1.6);
    bool ans = r1.compare(&r1, &r2);
    printf("%s\n", ans ? "true" : "false");
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Rectangle
{
    double width;
    double height;
    
    double (*get_area)(struct Rectangle*);
    bool (*compare)(struct Rectangle*);
};

double get_area(struct Rectangle* this)
{
    return this->width * this->height;
}   

bool compare(struct Rectangle* this, struct Rectangle* other) {
    return this->get_area(this) > other->get_area(other);
}

struct Rectangle* new_rectangle(double w, double h) 
{
    struct Rectangle* r = malloc(sizeof(struct Rectangle));
    if (!r) return NULL;
    r->width = w;
    r->height = h;
    r->get_area = &get_area;
    r->compare = &compare;
    return r;
}

void delete_rectangle(struct Rectangle* this)
{
    free(this);
}

int main()
{   
    struct Rectangle* r1 = new_rectangle(1.5, 2.6);
    struct Rectangle* r2 = new_rectangle(2.5, 1.6);
    bool ans = r1->compare(r1, r2);
    printf("%s\n", ans ? "true" : "false");

    delete_rectangle(r1);
    delete_rectangle(r2);

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, it doesn't really make sense to have `get_area()` and `compare()` be members of `Rectangle` in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Rectangle
{
    double width;
    double height;
};

double get_area(struct Rectangle* this)
{
    return this->width * this->height;
}   

bool compare(struct Rectangle* this, struct Rectangle* other) {
    return get_area(this) > get_area(other);
}

struct Rectangle* new_rectangle(double w, double h) 
{
    struct Rectangle* r = malloc(sizeof(struct Rectangle));
    if (!r) return NULL;
    r->width = w;
    r->height = h;
    return r;
}

void delete_rectangle(struct Rectangle* this)
{
    free(this);
}

int main()
{   
    struct Rectangle* r1 = new_rectangle(1.5, 2.6);
    struct Rectangle* r2 = new_rectangle(2.5, 1.6);
    bool ans = compare(r1, r2);
    printf("%s\n", ans ? "true" : "false");

    delete_rectangle(r1);
    delete_rectangle(r2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie because they really don't need to be, and should not be, allocated dynamically in the C++ example to begin with (they are being leaked). But in any case, my 2nd C example is closer to the C++ code by allocating the structs dynamically.

Comment: Yes, your second example is closer to the C++ code and tries to mimic the syntax, but at the cost of extra overhead in the `Rectangle` structure. You might consider `delete_rectangle` instead of `destroy_rectangle`  as it really emulates the `delete` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation is not semantically correct: the `Rectangle` structure does not need to have function pointers for the methods. In the C++ code, the methods are not `virtual`, so the compiler determines which functions to call from the type of the arguments: translating this to C puts this burden on the programmer, who must name the methods more explicitly and call them appropriately.

Here is a closer translation (ie: closer to what the c++ compiler actually generates):

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct rectangle {
    double width, height;
} rectangle;

rectangle *rectangle_construct(rectangle *this, double w, double h) {
    this->width = w;
    this->height = h;
    return this;
}

rectangle *rectangle_new(double w, double h) {
    return rectangle_construct(malloc(sizeof(rectangle)), w, h);
}

void rectangle_destroy(rectangle *this) {
    // no members need destroying
}

void rectangle_delete(rectangle *this) {
    rectangle_destroy(this);
    free(this);
}

double rectangle_get_area(rectangle *this) {
    return this->width * this->height;
}

bool compare(rectangle *this, rectangle *that) {
    return rectangle_get_area(this) > rectangle_get_area(that);
}

int main() {
    rectangle *r1 = rectangle_new(1.5, 2.6);
    rectangle *r2 = rectangle_new(2.5, 1.6);
    bool ans = rectangle_compare(r1, r2);
    printf("%s\n", ans ? "true" : "false");
    // in your code, you should add these lines
    //delete r1;
    //delete r2;
    //  emulated as
    rectangle_delete(r1);
    rectangle_delete(r2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got two things wrong (1) The functions in a struct have to take a pointer to the Struct as a parameter, necessarily. In C++ this happens implicitly, in C you need to write it in the code. Failing to do so is not a syntax error, but is definitely undefined behavior. (2) You failed to malloc the pointer to struct you created, this means any dereference will sure to be a segfault. I made the corrections and then your code worked fine. Check it out. Cheers!!!

´´´

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Rectangle{
    double width;
    double height;

    void (*new_rectangle)(struct Rectangle* self, double, double);
    double (*get_area)(struct Rectangle* self);
    bool (*compare)(struct Rectangle* this, struct Rectangle* other);
};

void new_rectangle(struct Rectangle* self, double w, double h){
    self->width = w;
    self->height = h;
}

double get_area(struct Rectangle* self){
    return self->width * self->height;
}   

bool compare(struct Rectangle* this, struct Rectangle* other) {
    return (get_area(this) > get_area(other));
}


int main(){   
    struct Rectangle* r1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Rectangle));
    new_rectangle(r1, 1.5, 2.6);
    struct Rectangle* r2= malloc(sizeof(struct Rectangle));
    new_rectangle(r2, 2.5, 1.6);
    bool ans = compare(r1, r2);
    printf("%s\n", ans?"true":"false");

}
```

´´´